# Terminal history up/down broken if last command output does not end in newline (KDE Konsole)

Tags: terminal, konsole

There is a strange behavior in all or most Linux terminal, which has bugged me for a long time. I am not sure if it is a bug or intended, or a configuration issue. So I ask here first.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Open a terminal.
- Optional: Run `export PS1='~ \$'`, to standardize this setting. Feel free to play around with this setting.
- Run `echo -n hello`.
- Use "Up" key to get the previous command.
- Use "Down" arrow key to get back to the empty prompt.
- Use "Up" again.

#### Expected

(this is with my own $PS1 that leaves `~ $`.)

After running `echo -n hello`:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hello~ $
```

After "Up" arrow key:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hello~ $ echo -n hello
```

After "Down" arrow key:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hello~ $
```

After second "Up" arrow key:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hello~ $ echo -n hello
```

#### Actual

(this is with my own $PS1 that leaves `~ $`.)
(first two steps as in "Expected")

After "Down" arrow key:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hell
```

After second "Up" arrow key:

```
~ $ echo -n hello
hellecho -n hello
```

#### Variations

- Use different values of $PS1.
- Use strings of different lengths in echo.
- Go further back in the history. For me, some history values have a different effect than others.

#### My terminal

I am using

> Konsole
> Version 21.12.3

But I think I saw this also in other terminals in the past.
I don't know if KDE "Konsole" is responsible for this behavior.

#### Additional information

(in response to comments below)

<strike>It does *not* happen for user "root"!</strike>

Initially I saw a difference between my own user and user `root`. But it turned out this was only due to differences in the `$PS1` setting. After normalizing this value to `'~ \$'`, or `'${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ '`, I now see same behavior for root and myself.

It also happens in bash inside a docker container which has a completely independent setup.

#### Links

For the record, I opened an issue here, https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=464384

Comment: Can you reproduce this in another terminal? What if you log in as a different user? What if you try a different shell (`sh` or `dash` should be available). What shell are you using?

Comment: Seems to be bash. If I use dash or sh, the up/down keys just produce `^[[A` and `^[[B`.

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: OK and other terminals?

Comment: `echo $TERM` -> `xterm-256color`. Now I am not sure what to look for and what to change.

Comment: No, I mean another terminal. You said you suspect this might be specific to konsole and that you think you saw it in other terminals. So I am asking you to try another terminal and see if you can reproduce it. Your system will likely already have `xterm` installed, but there should be various other terminal emulators in your system's repositories. Try one and see if the issue is indeed a bug in `konsole` or a more general thing with your setup.

Comment: So I started mate-terminal (while still in KDE), and see the same behavior. I also tried a Ctrl+Alt+F3 where I get a non-graphical terminal, and get the same there. But all of these use xterm and bash.

Comment: Unable to reproduce that under konsole-22.08.3

Comment: None of these use `xterm`, xterm is a different terminal emulator, your `$TERM` variable is something else. Anyway, please [edit] your question and add all of this extra information. And please also try as a different user so we can see if it is specific to your setup.

Comment: After normalizing `$PS1`, I see the same behavior for other users.

Answer (score 1):

That's just bash (actually readline) thinking that the prompt starts at the leftmost position of the current line, then when you press Down, just moving to position 5, and clearing to the end of line.

When you press Down, bash sends the following to the terminal:

```
\r\33[C\33[C\33[C\33[C\33[K
```

That's a carriage return to move to the leftmost position of the current line, four (the length of the prompt) CUF (Cursor Forward) control sequences, and an EL (Erase in Line) control sequence, which with parameter 0 (default) clears from the current cursor position to the end of the line.

Comment: Ok, this is good to know. Can anything be done about it?

Comment: @donquixote: not that I know of